# Get data from MongoDB query ( in Auth0 rules)

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, auth0

I can´t get data from my mongoDb (it´s hosted in Mlab), always returns the same error: user does not exist.
It´s a very simple query but I don´t seem to be able to get it right. My user has an email and a role in the database, so I´m trying to query based on the email and get the role.

```
mongo('mongodb://user:pass@data.mlab.com:port/database',
          function (db) {
      console.log(user.email);
      var users = db.collection('users');
      var result = users.findOne({email: 'email@email.com'});
      var role = result.role;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct mLab URI? that doesn't look like one

Comment: @CharisTheo Yeah I´m sure. It´s the same uri i´m using elsewhere in my app and it works there.

Answer (score 1):

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; // Promise fix if you will use mongoose

mongoose
  .connect(
    "mongodb://user:pass@data.mlab.com:port/database",
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useMongoClient: true }
  )
  .then(db => {
    let dbo = db.db("database");
    let query = { email: "email@email.com" };
    dbo
      .collection("users")
      .find(query)
      .toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // remember it returs array
        // you can map this array
        // like this -> result.map(user => console.log(user.role))
        console.log(result);
        db.close();
      });
  })
  .catch(console.log);
```

try to use mongoose and make sure you use your own promises as described [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html)

Comment: Thank you, but i´m still unable to fetch data like this. Will keep trying :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mongo('mongodb://user:pass@data.mlab.com:port/database', function (db) {

      var users = db.collection('users');
      users.findOne({email: 'email@email.com'}, , function (err, user) {
          if (err) return callback(err);

          if (!user) return if (!user) return callback(new WrongUsernameOrPasswordError(email)

          var role = result.role;

      });
```

You can also look into the MongoDB login template used in Custom Database connections scripts: https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/custom-db/templates/login#mongodb